# Python: how to transform relative coordinate to absolute coordinate in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to realize screenshot on a canvas, but the `ImageGrab.grab()` function is based on absolute coordinates so the image it saved is not what I intercepted. How can I transform relative coordinate of canvas to absolute coordinate?  I used `canvasx()` but it didn't work.

```
screen = (min(sbox[0],ebox[0]),min(sbox[1],ebox[1]),max(sbox[0],ebox[0]),max(sbox[1],ebox[1]))
img = ImageGrab.grab(screen)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [winfo_rootx](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_rootx-method) and [winfo_rooty](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_rooty-method) to get the x,y of the upper-left corner of the widget in screen coordinates. Add that to the coordinates relative to the window to get absolute coordinates.

Comment: Thank you very much! i've been seaching for these 2 funcs so long...new here! thank you!!

Comment: Thanks. Having discovered winfo_rootx and -y elsewhere, I continued searching because I had thought they would return coordinates relative to their own parents. and so on up the chain. Your comments saved further searching.